# Sphinx Index won't multiple a Decimal Field

Tags: sphinx

I have a Decimal field in my MySql Table. It was not indexing correctly in Sphinx as sql_attr_uint (decimals came in as 0). My quickest solution was to do Field*100 to convert any decimals to integers however then on rotate I got

```
warning FIeld attrbute not found ignoring
```

I'd hate to change the field in the db as I'd need to modify a # of queries. How do I store the integer values or multiple them so they get stored correctly.

Comment: Wonder did you do something like `SELECT id,title,price*100 FROM ...` in which case the column is actully called `price*100` in the result, so would need `,price*100 AS price FROM` to get a attribute still called 'price'. Using an integer attribute still quite attractive as avoids some issues with floating point math/comparisons.

Comment: @barryhunter Argh just not thinking man. Thanks. Are you saying though if in a Sphnx Query I now do "Select.... order by price DESC" I might get inaccurate results?

Comment: ordering by float should work, but maybe a bit slower than integer. The main issue is in comparisons. saying "WHERE price = 2.99" might not work (because the float ends up storing 2.99001 or similar, or 2.989991) -- in reality probably ok with just two decimal places, but if talking about more, maybe not. From the docs "the equality comparisons (ie. = and <> operators) introduce a small equality threshold (1e-6 by default)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. sql_attr_float. Sorry. Anyway instead of deleting I answered in case anyone else is as lazy as me :)